# Why am I getting authentication_redirect_to_virtual_host error?

Tags: c#, web-services

I am calling a web service that is online.
Sometime (not all the times), it crashes and gives me the following exception:

```
Redirect (authentication_redirect_to_virtual_host)

You are being redirected to the authentication virtual host.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

But I can open the web service from the browser normally.
**Why am I getting this error? and how to solve it?**
Note that I am passing the correct credentials to the web service.

Answer (score 1):

any chance you are using a blue coat proxy server? That was an issue I ran into and it required the network team to create a rule to allow traffic from the webserver to the web service/REST i was accessing.